# searching for a utility that provides implementation based on function type

Tags: haskell

Some time ago I came across a utility that, given a function's signature, provides its implementation (parametricity). I cannot recall it right now. Please help

Comment: In general you can use hoogle (www.Haskell.org/hoogle) for that. However I'm not sure you are looking for that?

Comment: Well, Hoogle gives you a library search. It seems that the poster is looking for a tool that will _generate_ an implementation rather than looking it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Djinn](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/djinn).

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this is what IttayD was thinking of, but what djinn does isn't really related to parametricity at all.

Answer (score 0):

I think Djinn is indeed the tool you're looking for (see Alexey Romanov's answer). Like Daniel points out, Djinn isn't related to parametricity, but perhaps you were mistaken with [this tool from the University of Bonn](http://www-ps.iai.uni-bonn.de/cgi-bin/free-theorems-webui.cgi)?

Answer (score 0):

[Reversing Haskell typechecker: converting from undefined to defined](http://okmij.org/ftp/Haskell/types.html)